# Why is there a definite article in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, déterminants

I've recently seen [this book cover](https://www.amazon.ca/Treize-raisons-Jay-Asher/dp/222619553X/ref=sr_1_1/133-1498415-1072830?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1511183180&sr=1-1&keywords=9782226195531). It says:

> Elle est morte. Pour treize raisons. Tu es l'une d'elles.

I assume

> Tu es l'une d'elles

means "You are one of them". Why is there a definite article before "une"? What grammar rule requires you to put an article before that "une"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no grammar rule that forces one to put a definite article. The cover could as well have said

> Tu es une d'elles.

According to Grevisse's book, the definite article in "l'un(e)" serves two purposes: it sounds better, and it is part of "elevated language" (as opposed to colloquial language). It can also help to avoid hiatuses (two vowels in succession, as in "tu es une [...]" which doesn't flow right when you pronounce it). But grammatically, there is no rule which forces you to use it.

Comment: Pourriez-vous svp. préciser à quel [ouvrage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Grevisse#Bibliographie) de Grevisse vous référez, avec l'article et l'édition ; votre propos au sujet de l'existence d'une règle est exact mais vous ne semblez pas référer au contenu de LBU14 §743 dont la teneur me semble différente. Votre propos est-il une extrapolation des considérations rattachées à [_on/l'on_](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3107) ? L'entrée à la BDL sur le sujet tient un propos [similaire](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3825) au vôtre. Merci !

Comment: Voir aussi [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/une/2) et les remarques au [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/un) pour diverses réflexions/exemples à ce sujet... [Larousse en ligne](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/un_une_uns_unes/80516/difficulte) est aussi intéressant. @Lambie The question is really is there a grammar rule to such an effect; overwhelming usage may rule but wouldn't make a grammar rule, I would think. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On peut dire : «Une des raisons pour lesquelles j'ai fait ceci ou cela»

mais on ne peut pas dire : «Tu es une d'elles» (aucun Français ne dira cela ni en langage soutenu ni en langage familier)

On doit donc dire : «Tu es l'une d'elles» ou bien «Tu es l'une d'entre elles»

A mon sens, la principale raison pour mettre un article défini juste avant l'article indéfini "une" réside dans le fait que l'objet auquel on se réfère, ie "raisons" est placé **avant** le mot "une".

---

You can say: “Une des raisons pour lesquelles j'ai fait ceci ou cela”

but you can't say: “Tu es une d'elles.” (No native will ever say this)

You have to say: “Tu es l'une d'(entre) elles”

According to me, the main reason why you should put the definite article is because the object referred to, “raisons”, is **before** the article "une".